# Read only textfield editable via inserted javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, readonly

I have a form with a read only field for display/submit to the next page purposes.

However, I noticed using developer tools in Chrome, I was able to **add an id to an element, use the javascript console to select that element, and change its value**. I submitted the form and what do you know - the next page acted on it as if it was the original value.

Now, there shouldn't be any problem with the people using the site I'm building, but it seems like a huge security flaw to me. Isn't the point of read-only to remain constant? If a savvy user to change it around, doesn't that pose a big problem? In fact, I didn't even think you could add and change attributes in chrome.

Please post your thoughts below, and let me know if there's a solution ("disabled" textfield, but setting the disabled property doesn't send the data to the next page).

Comment: This is why we have to sanitize user input. If it's something you don't want them to edit, don't put it on the form.

Comment: You can do this in Chrome, Firefox, even IE...

Comment: If you have a URL to which content can be posted, you have to write your code at the server to expect literally *anything* to be posted. The user is in *complete* control of the browser and of what gets posted to your site. That's always been the case on the web - it's just the nature of the system.

Comment: there is no way to prevent a user from using javascript to alter an input.  Readonly is only a browser hint to disable normal user input.

Comment: The point is not which browsers can do it; I am quite aware of developer tools in other browsers. It is not really even about sanitization either - unless you mean checking that the textfield was what the original value was (and the only safe way to store variables are with sessions?!!?)

Comment: @Raeki, yes, the basic rule of thumb is the *only* data you can trust is the data on your server. And, even then, only data that was properly sanitized and checked is good data. Also, session variables aren't even 100% secure. Sure, the information is stored on the server, but if you aren't doing additional checks (and using HTTPS), this can be *read* by others pretty easily (assuming you're letting the owner of the data read it), especially for users using public wi-fi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***NEVER** trust input from a web form.*

The user could, just as easily, remove the `readonly` attribute and edit the value. The `readonly` attribute is only something to *help* the user when filling out the form, so they don't edit a value expecting it to change, when your server actually won't let it be changed. So, always remember to code the behavior on your server first, and have the HTML form be a helpful guide for users to make the form easier to fill out (without having to submit the form several times to get relevant error messages).

To overcome this, if something is `readonly` and you do not want it edited, you could store the value in your database. Also, values provided by users should *always* be checked (and sanitized) as no amount of JavaScript, HTML, or CSS is going to prevent someone who knows what they're doing from adding new or changing/removing existing values.

Comment: The user can also add other inputs, with fields that you don't expect to be there. They can add `<option>` elements to `<select>` lists. They can change values of hidden input fields. Etc etc.

Comment: @Pointy, "no amount of JavaScript, HTML, or CSS is going to prevent someone who knows what they're doing from changing submitted values." Somewhat unclear, but this refers to being able to add new or remove/change current values.

Comment: Yes I agree - sorry I was not trying to contradict what you said, just to add some explicit examples (for the benefit of future Stackoverflow readers :-)